# Python replace values in list

Tags: python

I often write code like this:

```
newarguments = []
for argument in arguments:
    if parser.is_label(argument):
        argument = str(labels[argument])
    newarguments.append(argument)
```

but this feels really unpythonic. Is there a better way to loop over a list and replace certain values?

Comment: This question lacks context. See [ask]. What are the inputs and outputs? What is the `parser`? Please be specific. If, by "I often write code like this", you are asking for advice about unspecified hypothetical code, then this question is off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: @200_success I don't really think that matters in this case since I was asking how to loop over a list and replace values in a Pythonic way (this pattern often comes back in my code). If that makes it off-topic, I'll add some context tomorrow. It would be a shame to delete this question since alecxe wrote such a good answer. Should this be moved to Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way to collapse a list "mapping" code block like this is to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) combined with a [ternary conditional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461905/python-if-else-short-hand):

```
newarguments = [str(labels[argument]) if parser.is_label(argument) else argument 
                for argument in arguments]
```

List comprehensions are also generally faster ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops)).

Comment: I considered list comprehension before asking this question, but didn't know about the 'else', leading to a bug that removed all non-labels. The docs you linked also don't mention that an else can be used in a list comprehension. I love to learn these 'hidden' features in Python!

Comment: @redfast00 gotcha, added a note about the if/else shorthand expression for completeness sake. Thanks.